# Maria DB recommended RAM,disk,core capacity?

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-connect-engine

I am not able to find maria DB recommended RAM,disk,number of Core capacity. We are setting up initial level and very minimum data volume. So just i need maria DB recommended capacity.

Appreciate your help!!!

Comment: Well, if you don't plan to install it on a toaster [it should work everywhere](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-hardware-requirements/).

Comment: Just remember that the important part is, that when you have MariaDB installed on your server, you need to tweak the MySQL.cnf file based on your server's hardware.

Answer (score 6):

Seeing that over the last few years Micro-Service architecture is rapidly increasing, and each Micro-Service usually needs its own database, I think this type of question is actually becoming more appropriate.

I was looking for this answer seeing that we were exploring the possibility to create small databases on many servers, and was wondering for interest sake what the minimum requirements for a Maria/MySQL DB would be...

Anyway I got this helpful answer from  [here](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/starting-mysql-on-low-memory-virtual-machines/) that I thought I could also share here if someone else was looking into it...

> When starting up, it (the database) allocates all the RAM it needs. By default, it
>   will use around 400MB of RAM, which isn’t noticible with a database
>   server with 64GB of RAM, but it is quite significant for a small
>   virtual machine. If you add in the default InnoDB buffer pool setting
>   of 128MB, you’re well over your 512MB RAM allotment and that doesn’t
>   include anything from the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

1 CPU core is more than enough for *most* MySQL/MariaDB installations.

512MB of RAM is tight, but probably adequate if only MariaDB is running.  But you would need to aggressively shrink various settings in `my.cnf`.  Even 1GB is tiny.

1GB of disk is more than enough for the code and minimal data (I think).

Please experiment and report back.

There are minor differences in requirements between Operating system, and between versions of MariaDB.

Turn off most of the Performance_schema.  If all the flags are turned on, lots of RAM is consumed.

20 years ago I had MySQL running on my personal 256MB (RAM) Windows box.  I suspect today's MariaDB might be too big to work on such tiny machine.  Today, the OS is the biggest occupant of any basic machine's disk.  If you have only a few MB of *data*, then disk is not an issue.

Look at it this way -- What is the smallest smartphone you can get?  A few GB of RAM and a few GB of "storage".  If you cut either of those numbers in half, the phone probably cannot work, even before you add apps.

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense. You can definitely run MariaDB under 500MB. The amount of RAM required depends on how much you want to cache in memory fo queries.

Comment: Seeing that the question was for a very minimal and entry level db, I appreciated the answer without just hearing that "it depends". So when someone at least tries to give a number (even not perfect) then for many people it will helpful. Especially if you are wondering if 1MB or 10GB will be sufficient...

Comment: @AlfaBravo - I added some more text.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB or MySQL both actually use very less memory. About 50 MB to 150 MB is the range I found in some of my servers.  These servers are running a few databases, having a handful of tables each and limited user load. MySQL documentation claims in needs 2 GB. That is very confusing to me. I understand why MariaDB does not specify any minimum requirements. If they say 50 MB there are going to be a lot of folks who will want to disagree. If they say 1 GB then they are unnecessarily inflating the minimum requirements. Come to think of it, more memory means better cache and performance. However, a well designed database can do disk reads every time without any performance issues. My apache installs (on the same server) consistently use up more memory (about double) than the database.